# How to move uberSVN to another server?

Tags: ubuntu, svn, ubersvn

I clone my question from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/414537/how-to-move-ubersvn-to-another-server). I'm using uberSVN on Ubuntu server for my project development. Now I need to move uberSVN to another server (backup all data of uberSVN and SVN data).

How to move uberSVN to another server ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/414537/how-to-move-ubersvn-to-another-server

Comment: We prefer it if you don't cross post the same question on multiple sites. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to backup your repos as normal (the book linked above is the best source of info on that).

Next you'll need to backup uberSVN data (users, teams etc etc), you do this from the Administration tab, selecting backup.

Note: make sure both machines use the same version of uberSVN, or you may have problems.

Then install uberSVN on the new machine and reload all your data.

Comment: I think that you definitely wanted to post the answer at http://serverfault.com/questions/414537/how-to-move-ubersvn-to-another-server not here :)

Comment: I just commented on your post over there, as you were mostly right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Install new UberSVN and copy the repositories.
For each repository:

1. login to the source ubersvn with an administration account
2. select repositories / YOUR_REPOSITORY / administration
3. select dump/export (choose a filename and a directory at will)
4. copy the dump file to the new server
5. login to the new ubersvn server with an administrator account
6. create a new repository from the dump file

Hope this helps.